# join between two many-to-many tables

Tags: java, jpa, database-design, surrogate-key

I have some trouble defining appropriate database design for my java based web application. I have 3 tables(Tag, DT and Property) and my scenario is as follow. Each Tag can contain many Dts and each DT can be assigned to different Tags, each DT has many Properties and each Property can be used in many DTs. When a DT is assigned to a Tag, then the user can set values for all its properties.

My question is that how can I define a relation such that each Tag can have its properties' values base on the DT that is assigned to it. what are missing tables and relations in my design. I have to create relative Entities based on this db then.

```
Tag1==> DT1 ==> Initial values1, property values set 1 ; 
Tag2==> DT1 ==> Initial values1, property values set 2 ;
```

Here is the db diagram. And thanks for your help in advance.

[image]

Here is some sample data

[image]

Comment: It'd be good if you could provide sample data that you have in mind. Design looks overcomplicated without it.

Comment: ok here are some sample data. Im sure that I have a bad design here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The central issue with your design, as I see it, is the use of the surrogate keys.
It is not necessary to always create numeric single-column keys for tables.
And even if you do so, this doesn't guarantees you'll be free of duplicates.
This, in fact, forces system to keep more indexes on your tables, which is
an extra job to be done.

1. Some concepts:

   - I use singular for table names, 'cos each tuple in the table represents
     one object of the relation;
   - I use small letters for table and column names (identifiers) and
     big letters for the keywords. I don't like CamelCase in databases;
   - I use `<table_name>_id` for PK columns. It's also possible due to singular
     table names;
   - I use prefix + table name + details for all constraints and indexes I create.

   You don't have to follow them, but it'd be very nice to stick to a consistent naming
   patterns for your design.
2. I would start off with `property_type` dictionary:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE property_type (
       property_type   varchar(20) NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT p_property_type PRIMARY KEY (property_type)
   );
   ```

   It is a one-column table, that exists only to provide a domain of possible
   values for the properties types. I used `varchar(20)`, textual column is pretty
   fine. A benefit of this — you don't have to join back to this table via numeric
   keys to get what `property_type_id=123` means.
3. Properties:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE property (
       property_id     integer     NOT NULL,
       property_name   varchar(50) NOT NULL,
       property_type   varchar(20) NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT p_property PRIMARY KEY (property_id),
       CONSTRAINT u_property_name UNIQUE (property_name),
       CONSTRAINT f_property_type FOREIGN KEY (property_type)
         REFERENCES property_type ON UPDATE CASCADE
   );
   ```

   I decided to go with a numeric PK here, for I suppose you might want to rename properties
   at some point. And should you change `property_type`, updates will be cascaded.

   Despite the fact there's a PK here already, `UNIQUE` constraint on names is a must here,
   otherwise you risk to end up in a situation where you have equally named properties
   with different IDs.
4. DT table:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE dt (
       dt_id       integer     NOT NULL,
       dt_name     varchar(50) NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT p_dt PRIMARY KEY (dt_id),
       CONSTRAINT u_dt_name UNIQUE (dt_name)
   );
   ```

   Again, having just PK is not enough, creating also `UNIQUE` constraint.
   Though I would very much got rid of `dt_id` completely and would keep only
   `dt_name` and would have made it a PK.
5. Properties for the DT:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE dt_property (
       dt_id           integer     NOT NULL,
       property_id     integer     NOT NULL,
       initial_value   varchar(50) NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT p_dt_property PRIMARY KEY (dt_id, property_id),
       CONSTRAINT f_dt_id FOREIGN KEY (dt_id) REFERENCES dt,
       CONSTRAINT f_property_id FOREIGN KEY (property_id) REFERENCES property
   );
   ```

   This is the first big difference from your design — composite key is used.

   Yes, it means you'll have to carry out 2 columns whenever you want to
   refer to the entry in this table. But this is not a big deal, really — you
   design table once, you write your queries also once, but your software
   might be used for quite some time if it's done properly and easily maintained.
   It's better to spend a bit more time writing queries and get easily maintained
   system in the long term.
6. Tags:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE tag (
       tag_id      integer     NOT NULL,
       tag_name    varchar(50) NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT p_tag PRIMARY KEY (tag_id),
       CONSTRAINT u_tag_name UNIQUE (tag_name)
   );
   ```

   This is just another dictionary. Again, like for `dt` table, I would really want
   to avoid using `tag_id` column and keep just `tag_name`, making it also a PK.
7. New table `tag_dt` introduced:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE tag_dt (
       tag_id      integer     NOT NULL,
       dt_id       integer     NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT p_tag_dt PRIMARY KEY (tag_id, dt_id),
       CONSTRAINT f_tag_id FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES tag,
       CONSTRAINT f_dt_id FOREIGN KEY (dt_id) REFERENCES dt
   );
   ```

   This table is required to create `dt` + `tag` relations. Without it, you have data
   duplications — you can see it on your schema, you have 2 rows with `Tag_name='Tag1'`.
8. Finally, tag properties:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE tag_property (
       tag_id      integer     NOT NULL,
       dt_id       integer     NOT NULL,
       property_id integer     NOT NULL,
       a_value     varchar(50) NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT p_tag_property PRIMARY KEY (tag_id, dt_id),
       CONSTRAINT u_tag_property UNIQUE (tag_id, property_id),
       CONSTRAINT f_tag_property_tag FOREIGN KEY (tag_id, dt_id) REFERENCES tag_dt,
       CONSTRAINT f_tag_property_property FOREIGN KEY (dt_id, property_id)
         REFERENCES dt_property
   );
   ```

   This table is full composite keys and it conforms to all your requirements.
   Primary key is `tag_id, dt_id` and it is also a Foreign key to the `tag_dt` table,
   so you want be able to introduce something that hadn't been defined previously.
   Next, `tag_id, property_id` is unique, meaning tag's properties cannot duplicate.
   Finally, `dt_id, property_id` references `dt_property` table, which means that
   only properties allowed for that `dt` will be registered.

### Final notes

All Primary and Unique keys are implemented via indexes in most DBMSes. Also, some DBMSes
can use composite indexes (multi-column ones) even if first column of the key is omitted.
At least PostgreSQL can do it, this is what I use most.

Please, review your `dt` and `tag` tables, I highly recommend getting rid of the surrogate
keys in those, just like `property_type` is done.

I haven't created any extra indexes, typically I take this exercise after Data Model is implemented and some real queries are done against it.

Also, don't use `value` or `name` for column names. These are reserved words and you might have unexpected effects in the future incarnations of your DBMS of choice.

Comment: thanks @vyegorov, I didn't understand additional property_type table. in Property table entries are like this : id=1, property_name=size, property_type=String; id=2, property_name=length, property_type=Long;

Comment: @sina, this is correct. `property_type` is there to limit possible types you can use, so that values in the `property` do not end up being a complete mess. Some DBMSes provides `enum` types, also possible, but in my view separate table is a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

DB Design is completely fine.

Just use  Tag_DT and DT_Property Table

Below is a sample query

```
select a.id_tag,b.id_Property
from 
tag_dt a,dt_property b
where a.id_dt = b.id_dt;
```